# Is one Boolean variable per thread redundant?

Tags: c, multithreading, producer-consumer, condition-variable

I wrote this code in order to better understand producer consumer in a program where I require threads to wait for a task and then work in parallel to complete it.

I am wondering if I really needed an array for the `conditionMet` integer variables?
Could I not do the same with one integer?

Was there anything I could do to simplify the code?
My goal is to allow the main thread to hand tasks to the other threads.

Since this is just the skeleton, I am wondering if there is a way to simplify it?

```
#define  _MULTI_THREADED
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define  NTHREADS    7
#define  RUN_N_TIMES 3

pthread_cond_t      new_task_available  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t      task_complete       = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t     mutex               = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

volatile int        producerCond = 0;
volatile int        conditionMet[NTHREADS] = {};    
volatile int no_more_tasks = 0;
volatile int mini_tasks_complete = - NTHREADS;

void do_work(unsigned int* current_level){
  ++*current_level;
  printf("Thread %u has completed %u units of work.\nIt was #%d to complete it's task this round..\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), *current_level, mini_tasks_complete);
}

void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
  int* thread_cond;
  unsigned int level = 0;
  thread_cond = (int*)parm;
  while(!no_more_tasks){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    ++mini_tasks_complete;
    if(mini_tasks_complete == NTHREADS){
      producerCond = 1;
      pthread_cond_signal(&task_complete);
    }
    threads_waiting++;
    *thread_cond = 0;
    while (!*thread_cond) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&new_task_available, &mutex);
      if(no_more_tasks)
      {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        return NULL;
      }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    do_work(&level);
  }
  return NULL;
}

void reset_cond(int val){
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i)
    conditionMet[i] = val;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int                   i;
  pthread_t             threadid[NTHREADS];

  for(i=0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
    pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, threadfunc, &(conditionMet[i]));
  }

  while(threads_waiting < NTHREADS)
    sleep(1);  /* Sleep is not a very robust way to serialize threads */


  /* The condition has occured. Set the flag and wake up any waiting threads */
  printf("Waking up all waiting threads " "#RUN_N_TIMES" " times...\n");
  for(i = 0; i < RUN_N_TIMES; i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    mini_tasks_complete = 0;
    printf("New tasks available.\n");
    sleep(1);
    reset_cond(1);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&new_task_available);
    producerCond = 0;
    while (!producerCond) {
      printf("Main waiting\n");
      pthread_cond_wait(&task_complete, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }
  no_more_tasks = 1;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  mini_tasks_complete = 0;
  printf("Go home everybody!\n");
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&new_task_available);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  printf("Wait for threads and cleanup\n");
  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
    pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);
  }
  pthread_cond_destroy(&new_task_available);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&task_complete);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

  printf("Main done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like all the work will be done serially, not in parallel since you release the lock after the job is done. Also various globals that are changed by threads are should be volatile and changed with atomic operations, otherwise you'll get race conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to work in parallel and use volatile.